# Sortable list + ability to re-order each item by inputting rank #

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched and searched about how to do this, but to no avail.

Basically I have a pretty standard jQuery sortable list, using a gripper to allow users to rearrange the list

What I would like to add is an input box to each list item, autofilled with that item's #, that allows users to enter any number (so long as it is <== the total # of items in the list)< and then hit "Enter" or press a button to re-order the list.

Please see the YouTube Playlist tool or Netflix Queue as an example of what I am referring to:
http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/7715/youtubeplaylistrearrangc.png
http://www.thedigeratilife.com/images/netflix-queue-big.jpg

I cannot figure this out - Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Dave

Comment: what code do you have so far, can you post it please?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### jsfiddle:

## http://jsfiddle.net/pMcmL/6/

### HTML:

```
<ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 1
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 2
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 3
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 4
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 5
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 6
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
        <span>&#x21C5;</span><input type="text"/>Item 7
    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

#### http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

## +

```
li {
    margin: 1px;
    width: 130px;
    padding:2px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

li span {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height:100%;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgay;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

### Javascript:

```
sort_ul = $('#sortable');                  // * sortable <ul>
itemsCount = $('#sortable li').length;     // * total number of items
function updateIndexes() {                 // * function to update
    $('#sortable li input').each(          //   items numbering
      function(i) {
        $(this).val(i + 1);
    });
}
updateIndexes();                           // * start by update items numbering
sort_ul.sortable({handle: 'span',          // * apply 'sortable' to <ul>
                  stop: function(event, ui){
                          updateIndexes(); // * when sorting is completed,
                        }                  //   update items numbering
});
$('#sortable li input').keyup(             // * watch for keyup on inputs
  function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {           // * react only to ENTER press
        event.preventDefault();            // * stop the event here
        position = parseInt($(this).val());// * get user 'new position'
        li = $(this).parent();             // * store current <li> to move
        if (position >= 1                  // * proceed only if
            && position <= itemsCount){    //   1<=position<=number of items
          li.effect('drop', function(){    // * hide <li> with 'drop' effect
            li.detach();                   // * detach <li> from DOM
            if (position == itemsCount)
              sort_ul.append(li);          // * if pos=last: append
            else                           //   else: insert before position-1
              li.insertBefore($('#sortable li:eq('+(position - 1)+')'));
            updateIndexes();               // * update items numbering
            li.effect('slide');            // * apply 'slide' effect when in
          });                              //   new position
        }else{ li.effect('highlight'); }   // * if invalid position: highlight
}}});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is great. I had googled and googled this issue without finding anything so hopefully future googlers will find your great solution!

Comment: Bounty awarded. Well done. I was also triggering an Ajax update to the server once the sortable was done. In order to trigger the update after you've updated with the inputs you'll need to manually bind the update event and add your ajax logic in there: sort_ul.bind('sortupdate', function(event, ui) { ... ajax stuff ... }  and then call sort_ul.trigger('sortupdate') after appending the li back to the DOM so that it triggers the AJAX event. Thanks again!

Comment: I really like this but I want to use it as a form input, where can I find something that does that?

Answer (score 1):

here is something that moves the `li` items around by changing the numbers:

```
function setOrder() {
    $.each($('ul li input'), function(index, el) {
        el.value = (index + 1);
    });
}

setOrder();

$('ul li input').live('change', function() {
    var change = (parseInt(this.value) - 1);

    if(change > ($('ul li input').length - 1)){
        change = $('ul li input').length - 1; 
    }

    var index = $(this).index('ul li input');
    var move = $('ul li')[change];

    var arr = [];

    $.each($('ul li'), function(ind, el) {
        arr[ind] = $(this).clone();
    })
    arr[index] = move;
    $('input', move).val(index + 1);
    arr[change] = $(this).parent()[0];
    arr.sort();

    $('ul li').remove();
    var indexAt = 0;
    $.each(arr, function(index, el) {
        $('ul').append(el);
    });
    setOrder();
})
$('ul').sortable({
    stop: function(a, b) {
        var arr = [];
        var i = 0;
        $.each($('ul li'), function(ind, el) {
            arr[i] = $(this).clone();
            i++;
        })

        $('ul li').remove();
        $.each(arr, function(index, el) {
            $('ul').append(el);
        });
        setOrder()
    }
});
```

html:

```
<ul>
    <li><input/>lijrfxgjh</li>
    <li><input/>ghhgfhj</li>
    <li><input/>lijrjh</li>
    <li><input/>gfreydjgj</li>
    <li><input/>rey</li>
    <li><input/>gfjgf</li>
</ul>
```

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/bDvK8/

it is a bit glitchy, but it is a start

Comment: Wow! working like charm. it saved my day. Thanks @neal